# Android: when in web view: Does the browser cache the previous page?

Tags: android, caching, webview

My question is, when you are in  a webView, and you have gone through several pages.

You want to go back. Is the last page you have been to cached, so that you would not need internet connection to go back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, by default, `WebView` works like a regular Web browser. While it caches things, it still makes requests (with `If-Modified-Since` and related HTTP headers) to ensure that it has the latest editions. Also, `WebView` presumably honors other cache control directives sent by the server, perhaps to not cache certain things.

You can use `getSettings().setCacheMode()` on a `WebView` to modify this behavior somewhat.